# angularjs custom service integration testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I want to do integration testing of my AngularJs application. I want to test the actual service not mocking it. Somehow grabbing the instance of my service from the test does not work. Code is below:

```
var todoApp = angular.module('todoApp', []);

todoApp.controller('TodoController',  function ($scope, todoService) {

$scope.FinalMessage = 'Hello World!';

this.getTodos = function() {
    $scope.Todos = todoService.getTodos();
};

});
```

// TODO: move it to its file
    todoApp.service("todoService", function () {

```
// TODO: use the REST to grab the values...
this.getTodos = function () {
    var todos = [
        { TodoId: 1, Description: "Todo 1", Completed: false },
        { TodoId: 1, Description: "Todo 2", Completed: true }
    ];

    return todos;
    };
});
```

The test is:

```
describe("Integration testing with the Todo service...", function () {

describe("Todo Controller test", function () {
    beforeEach(module("todoApp")); // From angular mock not the real module!!
    it("Tests the controller returns the message", (inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        var $injector = angular.injector(['todoApp']);
        var myService = $injector.get('todoService');
        //var service = module.service("todoService", todoService);
        var scope = $rootScope.newValue();
        var controller = $controller("TodoController", { $scope: scope, todoService: myService });
        controller.getTodos();

        expect(scope.Todos).not.toBe(null);
    })));
});

});
```

somehow I cannot instantiate the todoService?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instantiate the service using the injector. The TodoService is already part of the TodoApp module so ng already knows how to find it and will instantiate it for you.

Try rewriting your spec like this:
(see working example on plnkr => http://plnkr.co/edit/Q2f6SJ?p=preview)

```
describe("Integration testing with the Todo service...", function () {

describe("Todo Controller", function () {

var $rootScope;

beforeEach(module("todoApp")); 
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_){
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));

it("Should return the message", (inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, todoService) {

    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var controller = $controller("TodoController", { $scope: scope, todoService: todoService });
    controller.getTodos();

    expect(scope.Todos).not.toBe(null);
})));
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To test my app with real backend calls I used a [modified version of `angular-mocks`](https://gist.github.com/kyro38/3371aaac54bf6583852f)

It works just like for unit-tests in Jasmine.

I'm using it with Jasmine 2.0, so a test looks like following :

```
it(' myTest', function (done) {
    _myService.apiCall()
        .then(function () {
            expect(true).toBeTruthy();
            done()
        });
});
```

NB: the `done` is needed because of the async call.